# How are unavailable United States Presidential elector's replaced before the electoral college meets to vote?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college

The members of the U. S. Electoral College are chosen in each state on election day in early November.  They meet to cast their formal votes In early December.

What happens if an individual elector, part of the winning slate in their state, becomes unavailable , seriously ill, or, well, dead during this four-week period?

Has this ever happened in any US Presidential election?